# Unit testing framework that supports hot reloading / hot reloading / live reloading / triggered restart / triggered execution?

Tags: api, unit-tests

So another words, [I just save my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989085/what-is-it-called-when-you-are-programming-and-a-program-automatically-updates-y) and it runs the unit tests automatically?

I'm mainly looking for an API like this for Javascript, python, node.js, Ruby and Powershell.

Comment: I am an embedded software developer. We don’t run tests on file save, only on commit to version control. We use Jenkins to do this, as it can hook Subversion (version control) and build the software and run unit tests  when anyone “commits” software to version control. You might want to use search terms/update your question  to use terms like `disk/directory/ file monitoring`  or `file change` to find an application which will monitor a give file or directory (tree) for changes and run a command which you specify.

Comment: Look for pages like this : https://www.raymond.cc/blog/3-portable-tools-monitor-files-folders-changes/

Comment: @mawg Those are good for Windows, but what about for Linux?

Comment: I guess you have to Google. Magic words "monitor linux filesystem for changes". E.g https://www.ostechnix.com/monitor-file-changes-using-fswatch-linux/